# How can one make a method receive one parameter that can be a string or char array?

Tags: java

The user has to be able to pass the `MyString` object a char array like `arr = {'g','o','o','d','b','y','e' }`, or a string such as "hello" 
I don't know where to get started because I don't know how to make a method that can receive a dual type..

Comment: You could overload it, but why bother?  Why allow both approaches in the first place?  It's probably more convenient to just stick with one of them, since it's so easy to convert.

Comment: Lookup `overloading`, it is two different methods of the same name but different types of parameters. In your case, you need to define two constructors for your class `MyString`, one that takes a `String` and another that takes a `char[]`

Comment: Looks like you just need multiple constructors to me.

Comment: @LouisWasserman my guess is because that is what the homework is

Comment: Thanks, it's for an assignment. I guess my prof just wants to know that we can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overload your methods:

```
public static String foo(String s) {
    // do something 
}

public static String foo(char[] s) {
    return foo(new String(s));
}
```

---

***EDIT*** In your title you say *method* but in your example you show *constructors*. Regardless, the same idea can be applied to both.

```
public MyString(String s) {
    // do something
}

public MyString(char[] s) {
    this(new String(s));
}
```

Comment: @MiserableVariable This certainly didn't seem like an "obvious homework question" (at least in my opinion - but I'm not saying it isn't). And besides, the code I did give is meant illustrate a concept, not explicitly solve his particular issue.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I will delete my comment

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like this would work

```
public class MyString {

    private char[] val

    public MyString(String s) {
        val = s.toCharArray();
    }

    public MyString(char[] c) {
        val = c;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return new String(val);
    }

    public char charAt(int i) {
        return val[i];
    }
}
```

This is pretty skeletonized, but it's how I'd approach it. Hope it helps :)